# Change background of X amount of cells in jquery

Tags: jquery

I need to make the form select box change the background color of the list item cells on the list below it for the number that is selected from the dropdown box.

So if a user selects 6 from the dropdown then the first 6 UL list items should change there background so they appear to be selected.

When the dropdown list is changed, it should save this value with ajax to a DB

I need to do this with jquery but I am stuck, I need to know how to change the first X amount of list item background colors and make the AJAX call on dropdown list change.

If a user goes to the page without even touching the dropdown list of numbers, it will be selected with the number pulled from a database so if the dropdown is selected as 12 from the database then the first 12 list items should have a differnt background color.  So doing it ONLY on change of dropdown list would not work as it should take into account if a valu is already set from the DB.

Below is the basic html part of it to show what I need to change.

Can someone good with jquery help me out please?

```
<select name="topfriendNumber">
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
</select>



<ul id="topfriends">
    <li friendID="0">
        <div>User 0</div>
    </li>
    <li friendID="1">
        <div>User 1</div>
    </li>
    <li friendID="2">
        <div>User 2</div>
    </li>
    <li friendID="3">
        <div>User 3</div>
    </li>
    <li friendID="4">
        <div>User 4</div>
    </li>
    <li friendID="5">
        <div>User 5</div>
    </li>
    <li friendID="6">
        <div>User 6</div>
    </li>
    <li friendID="7">
        <div>User 7</div>
    </li>
    <li friendID="8">
        <div>User 8</div>
    </li>
    <li friendID="9">
        <div>User 9</div>
    </li>
    <li friendID="10">
        <div>User 10</div>
    </li>
    <li friendID="11">
        <div>User 11</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that in just a couple of lines if you make use of the [lt selector](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/lt#index):

```
$('select[name=topfriendNumber]').change(function() {
    var val = $(this).val();

    //reset style
    $('ul#topfriends > li').css("background-color", "");

    //apply to all LIs before value of select
    $('ul#topfriends > li:lt(' + val + ')').css("background-color", "red");
}).change();
```

Comment: It partially worked before the update but now doesn't seem to change any cells

Comment: Thanks, it is working, I had the code in the wrong position on the page, the JS was too high in the page.  Just a couple of issues, if you select 6 it highlights 5, always 1 number less then it is.  Also if you go to the page and the number is already seletected like <option value="6" selected="selected">6</option> then nothing is highlighted

Comment: @jasondavis - that can easily be sorted, I'll throw in some more code.

Comment: 1 other problem, if you are able to help with any of it I would really appreciate your help.  if 6 items are highlighted and I drag a new item into place, it should adjust so it appears as the 6 highlighted cells are an overlay.  Sorry I don't think I mentioned that this is a drag and drop list before.  So if 6 items are highlighted and I move any item that is not in the 6 already, into to 6 highlighted area, then that new item is not highlighted

Comment: @jasondavis - the problem of not highlighting when you visit the page and something is already selected can be dealt with by invoking change() right after the event handler (see my edit). As for the draggy bit, I've never used draggable (or droppable) so I think you'd be better off asking that as another question.

Comment: @jasondavis - no worries. You are aware that you're the number 1 OP of the last 30 days (in the PHP tag) and the 7th of all time? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=php&sort=stats&pagesize=30

Comment: also I think it should work the same way with my drag/drop, on drop I think I can call the change function

Answer (score 0):

Should do the trick:

```
$("select[name=topfriendNumber]").change(HighlightLIs);
$(document).ready(HighlightLIs);

function HighlightLIs()
{
    var num = $("select[name=topfriendNumber]").val();
    var lis = $("#topfriends li");

    for (var i = 0; i < num; i++)
    {
        lis[i].css("background-color", "red");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or use the filter with a condition on the index of the mapped elements

```
$("select[name=topfriendNumber]").change(function(){
    $("#topfriends li").filter(function (index) {
              return index < $("select[name=topfriendNumber]").val();
            }).css('backgroundColor', 'red');});
```